# MusicBrainz Picard not writing album directory name

Tags: metadata, ripping

I am new to [MusicBrainz Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org) and am trying to use it to write the correct album directory name and song file names of files ripped from a CD that is unrecognized by [Asunder](http://littlesvr.ca/asunder/) (which is using `gnudb.gnudb.org`). The song file names are renamed correctly, but the album directory name is not.

The directory name should be able to be renamed too, right? If so, what am I doing wrong, how can I get that to work?

Also, how can I get the album image saved with the audio files?

Answer (score 1):

After you use 'Lookup' to find the album in the database:

- you can inspect the items in the Right-hand section and see that they have the correct metadata (Track titles AND Album title).
- Pull down the "Options" menu to make sure that both 'Rename Files' and 'Move Files' are enabled.

[image: screenshot]

- Open the app settings (Preferences) and look under `File Naming`.  You should see that `Move Files When Saving` and `Rename Files When Saving` are turned ON.

> [image: screenshot]

- Press **`Edit file renaming script...`** to check the file renaming pattern, or select 'Preset 1'.  Make sure your file renaming pattern (script) looks something like

```
%album%/%tracknumber%-%title%
```

with a Slash (`/`) character to cause a subfolder to be created.  *Your operating system might need a backslash (`\`) character instead.*

There are much better and fancier renaming patterns than the above example, like the "Preset 1" pattern below.  You can see it uses the slash character as a directory separator:

```
$if2(%albumartist%,%artist%)/
$if(%albumartist%,%album%/,)
$if($gt(%totaldiscs%,1),$if($gt(%totaldiscs%,9),$num(%discnumber%,2),%discnumber%)-,)$if($and(%albumartist%,%tracknumber%),$num(%tracknumber%,2) ,)$if(%_multiartist%,%artist% - ,)%title%
```

*Screenshots and command names are taken from MusicBrainz Picard 2.8/2.9, but other versions should be similar.*